# Understanding how to use NSRegularExpressions correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsregularexpression

I am trying to write a function that has an NSString and parses it returning an array of tags.

The definition of a tag is any nsstring text that starts with # and contains only alphanumeric characters after the #.

Is this correct?

```
#.*?[A-Za-z0-9]
```

I want to use matchesInString:options:range: but need some help.

My function is:

```
- (void) getTags
{
    NSString* str = @"This is my string and a couple of #tags for #you.";

    // Range is 0 to 48 (full length of string)

    // NSArray should contain #tags and #you only.
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The patten `"#.*?[A-Za-z0-9]"` matches a `#` which is followed by zero or more
characters which are *not* in the set `[A-Za-z0-9]`. What you probably want is

```
NSString *pattern = @"#[A-Za-z0-9]+";
```

The you can create a regular expression using that pattern:

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:0 error:nil];
```

and enumerate all matches in the string:

```
NSString *string = @"abc #tag1 def #tag2.";
NSMutableArray *tags = [NSMutableArray array];

[regex enumerateMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)
                     usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {
                         NSRange range = [result range];
                         NSString *tag = [string substringWithRange:range];
                         [tags addObject:tag];
                     }];

NSLog(@"%@", tags);
```

Output:

```
(
    "#tag1",
    "#tag2"
)
```